# Text-Align:center centers images too

Tags: css, html

Whenever I center text in my css, it also centers the images too. Why is that? The text is inside a div ("left") and the images are inside the second div ("right"). Here is the HTML -

```
<div class="left">

<p>

BANKS</div>

<div class="right">

<p>

<a href="#"><img src="http://www.dogtraining-hampshire.co.uk/dog_training_classes_puppy_1.jpg" border="0"></a> &nbsp; 

</div>
```

And the CSS -

```
#wrapper {
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
text-align: center;
}

.left, .right {
width:48%;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.left {
clear:both;
float:left;
margin-right:1%;
}
.right {
float:right;
margin-left:1%;}
}
```

I've tried adding "#wrapper img" to the CSS and setting the images to float left but this hasn't worked either.

Here is a jsfiddle of the full css and html - http://jsfiddle.net/rHEJA/

Answer (score 2):

> **Downvoters**
>
> Any reason for the downvote? I am happy to change my answer!

Images are **inline elements**, so they abide by the rules given in `text-align`. If you don't want them to follow it, you can very well give another rule like:

```css
#wrapper img {text-align: left;}
```

Or, in a better way, just to center the `div`, you can also do something like:

```
.centerDiv {width: 50%; margin: auto;}
```

This makes the `<div>` to be centred.

Comment: i had the same problem when i put one answer ant Jamie Read too (3 down vote on three different answer =) ). Coincidence ?

Comment: I tried adding adding an image alignment but it didnt work. It currently looks like this - http://static.tumblr.com/qh1bsky/lYQmw5l9v/screen_shot_2013-11-12_at_13.53.29.png

Answer (score 1):

This is just what `text-align: center;` does as a CSS property. Images will also align to the right if you set it to `text-align: right;`.

You can change your CSS to include the following:

```
#wrapper img { text-align: left; }
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't change it. The centered text is in the left div, the centered images (what I want to change) are in the right div. I tried putting the code in both divs but it didn't change

Comment: Create a [JsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with your HTML and CSS and i'll take a look.

Comment: @user2905081 Your HTML is poorly formatted is this what you are trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/d3XUw/

Comment: Sorry, I took out the links and images so they wouldn't come up in the search. Yes, I'm trying to achieve the text centered, the images not centered.

Comment: I just pulled out the `text-align: center;` and applied it to the `<p>` tags within `#wrapper`.

Comment: It doesn't work... now it looks like this http://static.tumblr.com/qh1bsky/lYQmw5l9v/screen_shot_2013-11-12_at_13.53.29.png